# JavaScript: ParallelArray vs Array of Arrays

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, parallel-processing, ecmascript-5

What is the main difference in JavaScript between parrallel Array and any Array/Array of Arrays/Multidimensional arrays?

Here are some links:

- [ParallelArray](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ParallelArray?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FParallelArray)
- [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray)

Basically I can't see any difference between:

```
var arr1 = [1,2,3,4];
var arr2 = [4,3,2,1];
var parArr = new ParallelArray([arr1,arr2]);
var multiDimenArr = new Array()
multiDimenArr = [arr1, arr2];
```

Comment: Your "multidimensional array" isn't, it is an array of arrays. (Well, first `multiDimenArr` is assigned to an empty array, then that empty array is discarded and `multiDimenArr` is assigned to a second array whose elements are also arrays. JS doesn't have "true" multidimensional arrays, just arrays of arrays.)

Comment: Don't use `ParallelArray` it's non-standard. Also, use array literal `[]` instead of `new Array()`

Comment: It says "The goal of ParallelArray is to enable data-parallelism in web applications." So to me it sounds like "parallel" has nothing to do with "array inside array". It just processes data differently, optimized for parallel computing. That would be my guess.

Comment: The "ParallelArray" concept is a very new idea intended to allow exploitation of multi-processor platforms from JavaScript. It's not even implemented in all browsers. It really has nothing to do with ordinary day-to-day coding (yet).

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick answers. Actually I think there is a great futures for these.

PS: Thank you for observations nnnnnnn and Xotic750.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know the browserside implementation details, but the difference is how the browser works internally with the array. If you have an ordinary array a `map` would do the mapping sequentially, i.e. elem1, elem2, elem3 ... A parallel array would allow mapping done in parallel, so the mapping process would be much faster.

Comment: So the difference is that, ParalleArray works in parralell and other is sequential. Why then Parallel Arrays aren't used as larger as others?

Comment: Your question is: why they aren't used more often? Because it's at this point an experimental feature and no standard.

Comment: Thank you Lilith I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

Actually after doing some tests, I found out that there is no difference between Array of Arrays and ParallelArrays. 
I've written the following code, and the results were the same, actually the processing time my be even slower on ParrallelArrays sometimes by ~ 1*10^-13 seconds. And that don't actually counts.
The difference persist on arrays of different dimesnions; I tried to make two simple array of 650 elements, and then on more test on arrays of about 1950 elements. Still there were only on tiny difference of ~ 1*10^-13 seconds.

[Example JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/ahoxob/1/edit)

PS. Take Care to run this into FireFox. and open console to see the result